# PHP script no longer works because of v.4 to v5 migration

Tags: php

Recently my webserver migrated from PHP v.4 to v.5.3.  I know, I know, long time coming :)

But now a number of my scripts do not display results when a user enters the required data.  Here is the script:

```
<?php 
if ($ok) {

    if ($heightft == "" || $heightin == "" || $weight == "") {
        $error = "<br><FONT COLOR=#FF0000>One of the fields above was not completed.</FONT><br>";
    } else {
        $bmi = $weight * 703 / (($heightft * 12 + $heightin) * ($heightft * 12 + $heightin));
        $bmiString = number_format($bmi,2,".","");
        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10' bordercolor='0000FF'><tr><td><strong>Your BMI is: " . $bmiString;
echo "<br><br></strong>";

        if ($bmi <= 18.50) { 
            echo "You are classified as <strong>Underweight</strong>."; 
        } elseif ($bmi <= 24.99) {
            echo "You are classified as <strong>Normal</strong>."; 
        } elseif ($bmi <= 29.99) {
            echo "You are classified as <strong>Overweight</strong>."; 
        } else { 
            echo "You are classified as <strong>Obese</strong>.</td></tr></table></bordercolor>"; 
        }       
    }
}

?>

<?php echo $error;?>
```

Comment: Never mind upgrading PHP late, are you *still* using `<font>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're expecting `register_globals` to be on. This is now off by default.

You should use `$_GET['heightft']` or `$_POST['heightft']` depending on the form method to access this data instead.

Comment: The variables that should be read from `$_GET['var']` or `$_POST['var']` instead of `$var` are: `ok`, `heightft`, `heightin` and `weight`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. So to clarify, I would alter: if ($heightft == "" || $heightin == "" || $weight == "") to if ($_GET['heightft'] == "" || $_GET['heightin'] == "" || $_GET['weight'] == "") ? Thanks again

Comment: You will probably need to edit `if ($ok) {` to `if ($_GET['ok']) {` too.